# return $map variable to a view from a controller ivory map laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I am trying to view a google-map on a view in laravel.using google api,
I used ivory-google-map https://github.com/egeloen/ivory-google-map/blob/master/doc/map.md

I managed to render map in controller.
what i need is to return this to the view with some other data.
here is my controller.

public function create()
    {

```
    $map = new Map();
    $map->setAutoZoom(false);

    $map->setCenter(new Coordinate(7.322723, 79.988258));

    $map->setMapOption('zoom', 10);
    $map->setAutoZoom(false);
    $map->setStylesheetOption('width', 600);
    $map->setStylesheetOption('height', 600);
    $map->setStylesheetOption('position', 'absolute');


    $map->setBound(new Bound(new Coordinate(7, 70), new Coordinate(7.3235001, 79.988258)));
    $map->getOverlayManager()->addMarker(new Marker(new Coordinate(7.322723, 79.988258)));

    $scaleControl = new ScaleControl(
        ControlPosition::BOTTOM_RIGHT,
        ScaleControlStyle::DEFAULT_
    );


    $map->getControlManager()->setScaleControl($scaleControl);

    $mapHelper = MapHelperBuilder::create()->build();
    $apiHelper = ApiHelperBuilder::create()
        ->setKey('AIzaSyA7pPqtVUC-JWLM89E7Rko')
        ->build();

    $map->setHtmlId('map_canvas2');


   echo $apiHelper->render([$map]);
   echo  $apiHelper->render([$map]);



    $materials = Material::pluck('mat_name','mat_price');
    return view('order.create', compact('materials');
}
```

map appears in the view,Along with data - materials.but the map is in top of the page,I figure it is because of echo in the controller.
i tried using

```
   return view('order.create', compact('materials')->with('maps',$map);
```

but still no luck.

I need to appear this map on a separate div,not top of the browser.which affect my other styles.

Is there anyway i can do this.
Here is my view,

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-1 margin-tb align-center">
        <div class="pull-left">
            <h2>Place New Oder</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="pull-right">
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('order.index') }}"> Back</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5  margin-tb align-center">
    <div id="map_canvas2">

    </div>

    </div>
    </div>
```

i want it to appear on #map_canvas2.Can anyone suggest an answer

Comment: Never `echo` or `print` inside a controller.

Comment: I think you put your maps key in your question, you might wanna regenerate it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove both `echo` from your controller.

Try passing `$apiHelper` to your view and then:

```
<div id="map_canvas2">
    {{ $apiHelper->render([$maps]) }}
</div>
```

Comment: ,i get undefined variable $apiHelper.here is how i return from controller, .... return view('order.create', compact('materials')->with('apiHelper',$apiHelper);

Comment: If that's the case, the error should say that `$maps` is undefined but not `$apiHelper` since you are passing it to the view. Pass both `$apiHelper` and `$maps`.

Comment: I just realized your `return view()` is wrong, it should be `view('order.create', compact('materials'))->with('apiHelper',$apiHelper)`.

Answer (score 0):

i found an answer,
i sent both apiHelper,mapHelper to the view,And echo them,And it works,

```
 return view('order.create', compact('materials'))
     ->with('apiHelper',$apiHelper)
     ->with('map',$map)
     ->with('mapHelper',$mapHelper);
```

Thanks @Camilo for the help !